# Definition: space endowed with canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra

As the title asks, what does it mean in linear algebra for a space to be "endowed with its canonical basis"? For example, if I'm describing a linear function from U to V where both domain and arrival space are endowed with their canonical basis. I'm using an English linear algebra textbook and it's not my first language, so I'm trying to fully understand all definitions.

Answer (score 0):

It means nothing in general, but, for certain specific spaces it means this:

- the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$ is$$\{(1,0,0,\ldots,0),(0,1,0,\ldots,0),(0,0,0,\ldots,1)\};$$
- the standard basis of the space of all polynomials with real coefficients and degree less than $n$ is $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1}\}$.